# 13” MacBook Pro Retina Late 2013 with U2720Q

Tags: macbook-pro, 4k

Does anyone know if the 13 inch MacBook Pro (late 2013) work with Dell U2720Q 4k monitor? Of course I won’t be using it at the full resolution but rather FHD or QHD, with the laptop itself closed. Just wanted to check if anyone has tried this combination.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it work? Like you said, you obviously wouldn't get 4K, but there's nothing that would preclude the monitor from working. With that said, I would use the DisplayPort connections (you'll need an mDP to DP cable) instead of HDMI.  HDMI is consumer grade AV connectivity and not really suited for computer environments.

Comment: Just the fact that it’s a 2013 laptop :). I don’t know if it’s powerful enough to drive a 4k display.

Comment: Also even if I use a Lowe resolution on it, I don’t know if technically it will have to drive more pixels. So I was wondering if anyone has tried it.

Comment: You're fine.  Monitors aren't hard coded to it's listed resolution - that's the max.  From a non-technical perspective, it would be counterproductive to introduce a product to the market where millions of devices couldn't connect to it.

Comment: Yeah, though 4k is fairly recent, and the Macbook pro 2013 was introduced 6 years ago, its more about the hardware compatibility, the specs have changed over the years. Wondering if the 4k would be too much for it. Would be nice to know if anyone has tried the combo..

Comment: mDP to DP doesn't seem to work, I keep getting "no dp signal from your device", any suggestions?